# Regex to replace comma to dot separator

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am trying to replace comma separator to a dot separator (and vice versa) in numbers, while lines may have other dots and commas. I tried using gsub(), but don't know how to stop it from recognizing replacement pattern as a character string.

For example, suppose I have a line

```
`Today I bought apples, oranges for 3,55 dollars`
```

where I want to replace comma separator to a dot separator at the price:

```
`Today I bought apples, oranges for 3.55 dollars`
```

A naive `gsub` approach doesnt work as I want to:

```
`gsub('[[:digit:]],[[:digit:]]',
      '[[:digit:]][.][[:digit:]]',
      'Today I bought apples, oranges for 3,55 dollars')`
```

which obviously gives `[1] "Today I bought apples, oranges for [[:digit:]][.][[:digit:]]5 dollars"`, i.e. gsub treats the replacement as a character line.

I cannot supply anything other than a string to `gsub()`. What can I do then? I have in mind that maybe I can write a function that will match this pattern, then basically replace `,` to `.` inside this pattern and place it back in the sentence. However, I hope there is a shorter solution for such a problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use capture groups and reference them in the replacement:

```
gsub("(\\d+),(\\d+)", "\\1.\\2", "Today I bought apples, oranges for 3,55 dollars")

# [1] "Today I bought apples, oranges for 3.55 dollars"
```

Comment: Could reduce the pattern to `"(\\d),(\\d)"`

Answer (score 2):

We can use a regex lookaround to match the `,` before a numeric and a numeric value and replace it with `.`

```
gsub("(?<=[0-9]),(?=[0-9])", ".", str1, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "Today I bought apples, oranges for 3.55 dollars"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- 'Today I bought apples, oranges for 3,55 dollars'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group each digit with parenthesis and recall them in the second part of the substitution. Below `\\1` recalls the first set of parenthesis and `\\2` the second set.

```
gsub('([[:digit:]]),([[:digit:]])','\\1.\\2','Today I bought apples, oranges for 3,55 dollars')
# [1] "Today I bought apples, oranges for 3.55 dollars"
```